# Area Lamp in Viewport in Blender Internal Engine

Tags: animation, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, glsl

I want to ask is there any way to make area lamp visible in viewport in Blender Internal Engine(GLSL) in Blender 2.79.
I cannot use Blender 2.8 due to some hardware limitations that is why I use Blender 2.79 Internal and Game Engine for my animation stuff.
Summary__How to get area lamp in viewport in Blender Internal Engine GLSL.

Answer (score 1):

Area lamps, as you may already know are not supported in BGE/UPBGE 0.2x, however we can still **bake** lighting such as area lamp lighting onto an image.

Cycles bake tutorial. The same can be done with Blender Render, just with different, compatible materials to that particular render engine.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pcjenAfFto